# Problems using Gmail with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, gmail

New guy here....
I have searched all over this site and tried multiple variations on my code, but I am still receiving a login error when I attempt to send an email through Gmail using Python 2.7. I have enabled the "less secure apps" thing on my Gmail account and I am still receiving this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\OC\Projects\Aquadat\Scripting\RawArcPyScripts\sendEmailWithAttachment_Aquadat.py", line 28, in 
    svr.login(sender,pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\smtplib.py", line 615, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14  Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 z33sm11383168qta.48 - gsmtp')

Here is the problematic code. I grabbed a lot of it off of this site and tried to adapt it to my application. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate

svr = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465)
svr.ehlo()
svr.starttls()
svr.ehlo()
sender = 'my_name'
pwd = 'my_pwd'
svr.login(sender,pwd)
rcvr = sender #Change to arcpy.GetParameterAsText(x) when working
def send_mail(send_from,send_to,subject,text,files,
              server):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            part = MIMEApplication(
                fil.read(),
                Name=basename(f)
            )
            part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
            msg.attach(part)


        smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
```

Comment: Possibly helpful, duplicate of [SMTPAuthenticationError when sending mail using gmail and python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email with Gmail as provider using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python)