# How can I unlock Google account captcha permanently to send emails in my heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-account

I have a rails app deployed in a free heroku plan and I'm using my Google account to send emails and I can only do this if the captcha is unlocked, so I go to my [account settings](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and allow access. But after a while, I have to do it again, otherwise I get the message:

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError

It took me years to figure out that this was the problem, but now I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Hello,  are you using the gmail api? (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby)  if so this question may have the answer you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python

Answer (score 3):

First try to close all open gmail accounts except the one you plan to use as the mailer and then visit this link https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
then click continue...
And also enable less secure app in this
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps.
And then push your changes in heroku will remove the SMTPAuthenticationError

Comment: I did it but after some days, SMTPAuthenticationError appears again :(

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create an app password, so when you try to login/send email with this, google wouldn't ask to 2 step verifications or things like that. [here you have the help page for that](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en&ctx=ch_b%2F0%2FDisplayUnlockCaptcha).

Comment: But I don't use 2 step verifications