# I've got a weird error while trying to send an email(to gmail account) from python code

Tags: python, email, gmail

I've got the following error when I tried to run my code through the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python files>sendemail.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python files\sendemail.py", line 18, in <module>
    mail.login(semail,spassword)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs5\n5.7.14 wGoV0BCEXzEk0wxtxU8ma6bwFe41jaXO7RaT8gE9mYRpUlxgmhO_Ycjqv18n50KWfE8cVD\n5.7.14 hSO50CoXj9t7zesCTQ1Ztt4dgRn19s-qdaHqAE-MlCjFonn7NxUcy6vkbAFeWQDDZ9RVUJ\n5.7.14 hypJBWeSGRCi_agtkf1tMgmWQE-Y6sNwcPObMDUK6MMXpDxgQMuXgdvrhalQEDEgRM81HY\n5.7.14 WS4Nmwt6gutUPZHIHUnomf-ZwIT7RBJfeOSjP8OXcQF0JEOcQm3Dur0_YJz7VFbz5KhzLZ\n5.7.14 ZLVFTfmY-RmSENzJwJY6U6iL0AhBUSlau2Ph6M5T507H1obC4JHgSNQCUdWPiILQAdkwoF\n5.7.14 t5gOoxatSDtzpHLRVffPHOd_X6K_O7M53xidmRghoNywgoY4wFWwrdhxsHz77COpbN1fQB\n5.7.14 67NMZBdYf06Mj3lacV0rqnXyhX59w8TE5VLjoPXGoC3EaepSSUeeymKXWwDs-J9_rFdSLd\n5.7.14 q14gU> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 e73-v6sm67293355pfb.153 - gsmtp')
```

The code I used was:

```
import smtplib

semail = "sender@gmail.com"
spassword = "pwd"
remail = "reciever@gmail.com"
content = "The code worked properly"

mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login(semail,spassword)
mail.sendmail(semail,remaill,content)
mail.close()
```

I am unable to understand what this error means. Please somebody suggest what changes should I do to make it run

Comment: Username or password incorrect?

Comment: Have you enabled the Google 2-step authentication? If you did, that might be the problem. https://www.google.com/landing/2step/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python Check this link

Comment: @AnuragAS that's not the same exception.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python What about this? This answer points to the other answer.

Comment: By the way, you also have a typo `remaill` in `mail.sendmail(semail,remaill,content)`.