# SMTPAuthenticationError at /password-reset/

Tags: python, django, django-settings, change-password, smtp-auth

I am new in Django. I am trying to add a feature in my project that enables user to reset his password through given email. These configurations are in development and not production. This is my configuration in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

I tried these but nothing seems to be working. I enabled IMAP from gmail settings as well.
Can you please help me what am I doing wrong in here!
In case if you want to see full error.

> SMTPAuthenticationError at /password-reset/ (535, b'5.7.8 Username and
> Password not accepted.
>
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a24sm3958276ljd.32 -
> gsmtp')
>
> URL:  http://localhost:8000/password-reset/
> Exception Type:   SMTPAuthenticationError
> b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a24sm3958276ljd.32 -
> gsmtp') Exception
> Location: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py
> in auth, line 642 Python
> Executable:   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.7.2 Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\django_project',
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages',
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages']
> Server time:  Thu, 4 Apr 2019 12:24:22 +0000Learn more at\n5.7.8Request Method:   POST RequestDjango Version: 2.1.7Exception Value:    (535,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you mind double checking if your environment variables are set correctly? Also, did you enable this feature on your Google account: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps?

Take a look at this answer, as it might help you as well: [SMTPAuthenticationError when sending mail using gmail and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python)

Comment: Yeah, thank you man. The first link provided above is the solution of this mess. My environment vars are set well.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was working on my local machine but not on heroku server. I went on this link https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
 and clicked on Continue. After that I had to re-login into my gmail account. It started working. Hope it might help someone!

Answer (score 1):

### Feb, 2022 Update:

You need to do **2 things** to get over **very strong google's security**.

1. Allow less secure apps: **ON** ↓↓↓

   https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
2. Allow access to your Google account: **ON** (Tap "Continue") ↓↓↓

   https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')` refers to your 'mail address' and not the name you set for your app password on your account setting!