# Accessing environment variables in production in Django deployed to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, environment-variables

I am developing a web-app in Django that needs to send automated emails. The `username` and `password` are saved locally in my `Windows 10` environment variables. The app is able to send emails locally, but in proudction once deployed to `Heroku`, the following error is raised:

```py
530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y7sm6660123qtn.11 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost'
```

My guess is that the environment variables are not being accessed which is why this error is thrown.

Here is my code in **settings.py**

```py
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('NAHE-USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('NAHE-PASS')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the environment variables (NAHE-USER, NAHE-PASS) in Heroku using [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).
There are injected at runtime and will be accessed by your code with `os.environ.get('NAHE-USER')`

Comment: Hi! I defined the environment variables in the Heroku settings. Created an ```.env``` file and a ```.gitignore``` file. It was able to send messages locally, but again, gave error in production when deployed to Heroku. This is the error I got: ```smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs\n5.7.14 GB4llPJX5FVtui_gBnweSpbtHJEJ_Qe4zyNLtysFdCPgXKd8gL7sOL Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 x9sm6885195qts.65 - gsmtp'```

Comment: It looks like a different problem, it appears you can get the env variables but the access is somehow rejected by Google. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python

Comment: Thanks so much! It appears that Google was rejecting the sign-in.

Comment: I have had the same experience with Yahoo, I had to lower/disable some security layers