# Flask application smptlib sender refused error after heroku deployment

Tags: python

message.send(connection)
2021-06-20T00:49:29.013482+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 427, in send
2021-06-20T00:49:29.013483+00:00 app[web.1]:     connection.send(self)
File      self.host.sendmail(sanitize_address(envelope_from or message.sender),
2021-06-20T00:49:29.013484+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 882, in sendmail
2021-06-20T00:49:29.013484+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
2021-06-20T00:49:29.013486+00:00 app[web.1]: smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y24sm8273493qtn.57 - gsmtp', 'xxx@gmail.com')

I have deployed my flask app to heroku and I am facing this email authentication error. On my local machine the email part is working perfectly. Only after deploying to heroku it is giving this error. I have checked all the email and password variables and also allowed less secure apps access. Can some one pls advise. I am using flask-mail

My code is

```
__init__.py
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

In routes.py
def send_reset_email(user):
    token=user.get_reset_token()
    msg=Message("Password  Reset Request",sender='xxx@gmail.com',recipients=[user.email])
    msg.body=f'''To reset your password visit the following link:
    {url_for('reset_password',token=token,_external=True)}
    If you did not make this request please ignore this message.
    '''
    mail.send(msg)
@app.route("/reset_request",methods=["GET","POST"])
def reset_request():
    form=ResetRequestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user=User.query.filter_by(email=form.emailmain.data).first()
        if user is None:
            flash("No account exists with this email. Pls register first.",'danger')
        else:
            send_reset_email(user)
            flash("An email has been sent with instructions to reset your password",'success')
            time.sleep(2)
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

In models.py

def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')


    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
```

Can someone pls tell me what I am missing

Comment: First of all, use code formatted for your errors. Second it says authentication required , see your inbox there might google security mail.  when you try to send mail

Comment: Did you add ```EMAIL_USER``` and ```EMAIL_PASS``` as environment variables in Heroku ?

Comment: No how to do that?

Comment: @charchit it works locally so there is no issue i think with gmail ,there might be some configuration missing on heroku. Can there be some issue from that end

Comment: @Ram I just added thosev variables to heroku. now its sayhing smtplibb authentication error, do i have to add all mail variables to heroku whichever were there in the python code:?

Comment: @anish You are getting Authentication error because Google blocks sign-in attempt by apps for security reasons. Please go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't allow you to sign in like that from heroku. You can do the following.

1. Check your mails, there might be one telling about signin into your account.
2. Go to [security](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) and enable enable less secure app.

Note -After doing so my app to worked, but one day it again gave the same error. I got this [DisplayUnlockCaptcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) link from a SO question. But I need to fo it whenever I send email. So finally I got this.

1. Go to [security](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/security) enable 2 step verification and head to app passwords.
2. Choose your device (I chose windows computer ) and in app select mail. App password will be generated. Replace your password with this password in heroku env variables.