# Python Bulk Mailer Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the code on this Github repo  - https://github.com/swaaz/Bulk-Mailer

The Main.py file is giving me the following error 'smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i5' .... however I am 100% that the username / password I am using is correct. NOTE: I am entering my username / password in line with main.py file below but have extracted for obvious privacy reasons.

```
import smtplib
import imghdr
import os
import pandas as pd
from email.message import EmailMessage

# your account credentials
maildid = "EMAIL"  # enter your email id here
password = "PASSWORD"  # enter your password here

files = []

# path of the folder which will be attached
path = "attachments"
attachments = os.listdir(path)

# creating a new list to store files along with path
for file in range(len(attachments)):
    files.append(f'{path}/{attachments[file]}')

# reading mail id's from excel sheet
cont = pd.read_excel("contacts.xlsx")
contacts = cont['mail id'].values  # storing all the mail id's in contacts list

for contact in contacts:
    message = EmailMessage()
    message['From'] = maildid
    message['To'] = contact
    message['Subject'] = 'Enter the Subject here'  # replace the subject

    """
    Note: if you want to send mail with content then use option 1 and delete the option 2
          or
          if you want to send HTML mail then use option 2 and delete option 1
    """

    # option 1
    message.set_content(
        'Enter the content here ')  # this is optional. if you are using web mails then this is not necessary.

    # option 2
    message.add_alternative("""\    
        <!DOCTYPPE html>
            <html>
                <body>

                    //Insert you html code here

                </body>
            </html>            
                            """, subtype='html')

    # attaching files to the mail
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            file_data = f.read()
            file_type = imghdr.what(f.name)
            file_name = f.name
        message.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='application', subtype='octect-stream', filename=file_name)

    # Sending mails
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(maildid, password)
        smtp.send_message(message)

        # if the mail is Successfully sent then this statement will be printed
        print("Mail sent Successfully to {}".format(contact))

print("\nSuccessfully sent!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

These may be relevant:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26852782/1113569

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Google blocks sign-in attempts from less secure apps.

Comment: ANYONE found a workaround with the above code. I have tried for quite a while and the fixes in the above post aren't really fixes